# Nautilus resize to increase image size does not work with Scale option

Tags: 20.04, nautilus, image-processing

With Ubuntu 2020.04.3 (Focal) I used Nautilus resize (i.e. right click the file in Nautilus) to increase the image's size using the Scale option. It creates a resized image file with the same number of pixels when I used scale of (e.g.) 150 on a 582x582 image. I've tried it with both png & jpg files. however, when I specified the number of pixels for height & width (893x893) ,it worked OK.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: *Xenial* is 16.04; they reached the end of the alphabet and needed to start again with 17.10 (*artful*) and by 20.04 had reached *focal* or the letter F.  The current *development* release is now on *i* or *impish*, so your *Xenial* is 16.04 as you've tagged and that is not 2020.04; 2020-April was when it reached it's *end of standard support* and became off-topic on this & some sites (the start of 16.04 ESM or *extended* support).

Comment: Apologies. I made a mistake. I'm using 20.04.3. Thus, not Xenial but Focal.

Comment: The question needs to be fixed and the 16.04 flag removed if it was a mistake.

Comment: Question fixed to refer to Focal rather than Xenial